# Understanding reduction operation of accumulator - java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I m trying to understand reduction accumulator operation: In the below example

```
List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("a","bb","ccc");
String result123 = letters
  .stream()
  .reduce((partialString, element) -> 
      partialString.length() < element.length() 
      ? partialString
      : element
  ).get();  

System.out.println(result123);
```

Is  partialString initialized to empty string? Since its a fold operation, I assume that operation should result empty string but its printing `"a"`. Can someone please explain how this accumulator works?

Comment: Some pretty good examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for-loop` corresponding code for the `reduce` operation is like

```
boolean seen = false;
String acc = null;
for (String letter : letters) {
    if (!seen) {
        seen = true;
        acc = letter;
    } else {
        acc = acc.length() < letter.length() ? acc : letter;
    }
}
```

The first pair of element to reduce are `(firstElt, secondElt)` , there is no empty initial element

---

If you print each step of the `reduce`

```
letters.stream()
       .reduce((partialString, element) -> {
           System.out.println(partialString + " " + element);
           return partialString.length() < element.length() ? partialString : element;
       }).get();

// output
a bb
a ccc
```

Comment: The operation *always* returns an `Optional<String>`, not only when the stream is empty.

Answer (score 6):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), you will learn that `partialString` is initialized to the **first** value, and `reduce()` is only called to *combine* values, aka to reduce them.

> Is `partialString` initialized to empty string?

No. If you wanted that, you need to use the *other* [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method, so you wouldn't need to call `get()`:

```java
String result123 = letters
  .stream()
  .reduce("", (partialString, element) -> 
      partialString.length() < element.length() 
      ? partialString
      : element
  );
```

Of course, that doesn't make *any* sense, because `partialString` is now always a string with `length() = 0`, so result of expression is **always an empty string**. You might as well just write `String result123 = "";` and save all the CPU time.

Comment: Also a Google search turns up some nice examples how `reduce()` works.

Comment: @markspace Yeah, but why not check the definitive source first, i.e. the documentation. It's so easy to find/read when you use an IDE, that you actually have to go out of your way to ignore it when writing the code.

Comment: The documentation was give in code, not in written in words, except 'associative accumulation function'. If "associative accumulation function," meant what the code shown in for loop, then my bad

Comment: Im saying i expected it to be mentioned clearly as they usually do.  A sentence stating initial value of result is first element would have been clearer

Comment: Thanks for the additional answer with overloaded method

Comment: @user2296988 It very clearly states: *"`accumulator` - an associative, non-interfering, stateless function for combining **two** values"*. So the method won't be called until there are two values to be combined.

Comment: Im clearly not at that level yet to comprehend minute details